# Proving lg(n!) = O(n!)

Tags: math, big-o

I am having trouble coming up with a good  way of proving this for some reason.  I am very rusty on solving limits and math in general.

First of all: I am under the impression that you can separate limits under the multiplication law.  So, currently I am just getting to

> lim<sub>n→∞</sub>( lg(n)⋅n<sup>0.5</sup> ) ⋅ lim<sub>n→∞</sub> ( (e/n)<sup>n</sup> )

is the same as the limit of something times the limit of 0.  So, it must be 0.

Is this even valid, or should I go back and just learn to derive n<sup>0.5</sup>⋅lg(n) and other similar compound functions?

Obviously this problem is trivial, I'm just wondering if I was even taking a valid approach.

Comment: Of course you can't prove it. It isn't even true. `lg(n!)` isn't `n!` it's actually `lg(n!) = O(n*lg(n))`.

Comment: Yes, log(n!) ~n*lg(n) right? At least that is what my notes and books say.  So, why can't you prove that lg(n!) = O(n!) ? Seems that that is obviously true...

Comment: Just plot a graph of `lg(n!)`, `n*log(n)`, and `n!`. It's pretty obvious the last one isn't the same. No math required.

Comment: Oh wait, nvm, you're talking Big-O as in "less than or equal". I thought you were talking about Theta (double-sided bound).

Comment: It must be proved via limit rules for a class.  I got it right on a test, but I was not satisfied with how I got there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to prove. Remember that `f(z) = O(z)` iff there exist an M and z0, such that for all `z > z0`: `|f(z)| < M|z|`.

Now, since we trivially know that `|log(z)| < |z|` for all `z > 1`, we just can just substitute `z = n!`, and there's our proof. To be clear, `z0 = 1` and `M = 1` will do it.

If someone says this isn't true, they are probably forgetting that the most common Big Oh notation (Capital omicron) offers an upper bound, so the bound does not have to be tight.

**Update:** A note on the multiplication law for limits. You can only break up a limit like that if both limits **exist**. For instance, if you have the limit of n/n as n approaches infinity, you can't separate this to the limit of n times the limit of 1/n, since the limit of n does not exist. Your first limit clearly diverges, so you can't use this approach.

Comment: Correct.  Thank you.  I will say that my professor is looking for limit rule calculations, so I do not think this would be a valid answer for me.

Comment: You can also prove this by showing that lim sup {n->inf} | log(n!) / n! | < inf.